# How common is port-knocking?

Tags: firewalls, ssh, ports, port-knocking

Today I read about [port-knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) for the first time. It has been a pretty known concept for more than ten years, but I don't know anybody who uses it for their servers.

**How common is the usage of port-knocking?**

Comment: I've never seen it used in an enterprise.  However, I have seen firewall which lay dormant and can be enabled after telnet authentication (on page 463 of [this](http://www.datatechuk.com/download/documents/stonegate/stonegate_administrators_guide_v4-3.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Port-knocking is often used in 'closed' designs to assure network integrity. In the meantime it evolved into single-packet authentication.

Check here for the source of sources on the topic :)

http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/docs/SPA.html

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is pretty uncommon.

What I remember about it from what I learned in college is it has a pretty big downside : it's easy to deny someone access by sending a packet to a random port using his adress, and thus breaking the "knock" sequence.

However its evolution, single-packet authorization, is much more solid (though I have no idea if it is commonly used in practice).